# SPFX Content Query [Handlebars] Unable to get a valid URL from list Hyperlink column

Tags: html, handlebars.js, sharepoint-online, spfx, content-query-web-part

I am using the Content Query webpart for sharepoint online and try to query a hyperlink column from a list.
I am query my "URL" column for the bing address.

```
<div class="url"><a href="{{URL.htmlValue}}">{{URL.htmlValue}}</a></div>
```

But this returns

```
https://sharepoint-tenant/sites/%3Ca%20href=%22http://bing.com%22%3EBING%3C/a%3E
```

How can I just get the direct URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem correctly, but if you already have URL encoded, you can use triple quotes to avoid double-encoding with handlebars:

```
<div class="url"><a href="{{{URL.htmlValue}}}">{{{URL.htmlValue}}}</a></div>
```

Comment: I ended up just using a single line text and setting the <a href="{{URL.htmlValue">{{URL.htmlValue}}</a> instead. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the value for the URL? As far as I know, the value of hyperlink column should have a Description property and a Url property. You could just use the url property to get the direct URL.